# How can I read a pipe-delimited transaction file and generate the sales reports

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pipe delimited transaction file. I want to identify  the following from this data.

1. A report of the total revenue from each customer
2. A report for each customer showing how much of their spending went to each category.

---

```
Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42
Nitin|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00
Susie|groceries|cereal|5.50
Susie|groceries|milk|4.75
Susie|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00
Susie|fuel|gasoline|44.90
Pedro|fuel|propane|9.60
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: And also explain what the problem is. You've explained what your program should do. I assume it doesn't actually quite do that, or you wouldn't be here, but that's about all I can guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = """Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42
Nitin|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00
Susie|groceries|cereal|5.50
Susie|groceries|milk|4.75
Susie|tobacco|cigarettes|15.00
Susie|fuel|gasoline|44.90
Pedro|fuel|propane|9.60"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(mystr), header=None, sep='|',
                 names=['Name', 'Category', 'Product', 'Sales'])

# Report 1
rep1 = df.groupby('Name')['Sales'].sum()

# Name
# Nitin    15.00
# Pedro    11.02
# Susie    70.15
# Name: Sales, dtype: float64

# Report 2
rep2 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Category'])['Sales'].sum()

# Name   Category 
# Nitin  tobacco      15.00
# Pedro  fuel          9.60
#        groceries     1.42
# Susie  fuel         44.90
#        groceries    10.25
#        tobacco      15.00
# Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me how  to find the following .Show the sales tax component for each of the reports. (All the items have a sales tax of 9.25%.)

Comment: @mike, I suggest you ask as a separate question.. Not exactly the same method as `groupby`.

Comment: posted as a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290471/python-generate-reports-using-pandas